# How to skip onbeforeunload event when clicked on hyper links

Tags: jquery

I have got a page as shown below with similar code

```
<a id="goog" onclick="return togooglepage()"  href="#">Google.com</a> <br/>
<a id="yahoo" onclick="return toyahoopage()" href="#">Yahoo.com</a> <br/>


function warning(){
    if(true){


      return "You are leaving the page";
    }

}
window.onbeforeunload = warning;

function togooglepage()
{
    window.location = "www.google.co.in";
}

function toyahoopage()
{
    window.location = "www.yahoo.com";
}
```

I have got the window.onbeforeunload = warning to prevent from closes like click on cross button on the browser or click on Ctrl + W .

When any of the above actions happens

i want to execute

```
function warning(){
    if(true){


      return "You are leaving the page";
    }

}
window.onbeforeunload = warning;
```

But how can i skip this , when clicked on hyper links ??

Is it possible to avoid this ??

Comment: You tagged it `jQuery` but not used, you want to solve it using JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: anything is fine until it works fine .

Comment: Check **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/cezjbuky/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
function togooglepage()
{
window.onbeforeunload = null;
window.location = "www.google.co.in";
}

function toyahoopage()
{
window.onbeforeunload = null;
window.location = "www.yahoo.com";
}
```

Basically what yout want is to set window.onbeforeunload to null before window.location

Answer (score 1):

Just set some global variable to avoid warning, e.g.:

```
function warning(){
    if (!warning.disabled) return "You are leaving the page"
}
window.onbeforeunload = warning;

function togooglepage() {
    warning.disabled = true
    window.location = "www.google.co.in"
}
```